# Pulling Random Row from txt File

Tags: python, list

I have a text file named universitylist.txt. When the user's input matches the college name, the college and city are returned. I am trying to add an IF statement that will return a random entry from the file when the user enters "random college". I am searching for the best way to do this. I tried appending random.LineItem in the print statement but that doesn't work.

```
e#!/usr/bin/env python3
from random import random

def main():

    print("Welcome to University Locator!")
    user_input = input("Please enter the the name of the university or type 'random college'(press x to exit). ")

    city = ""
    while user_input.lower() != "x":
        with open("universitylist.txt") as file:
            schoollist_dict = {}
            for lineitem in file:
                lineitem = lineitem.replace("\n", "")
                school_city_list = lineitem.split(",")
                schoollist_dict.update({school_city_list[0]: school_city_list[1]})

            user_college = user_input.title()

            **if user_input == "random college":

                rando_entry = random.schoollist_dict(lineitem)
                print(rando_entry)**

            elif user_college in schoollist_dict:
                print()
                print(f"College: {user_college}")
                print(f"City: {schoollist_dict[user_college]}")
                print()
            else:
                print(f"The college {user_college} does not exist in our database.")
                print()

        user_input = input("Please enter the the name of the university or type 'random college'(press x to exit). ")
    print("Session Terminated")

if __name__ == "__main__": main()  # Main entry point for the applications
nter code here
```

Comment: Did my answer work?

Comment: It did display the random city. Ideally, I wanted the College and the associated city displayed. I was able to add the college as well and it works as it should. Thank you for your help!

Comment: ah right I can add that you should have said in a comment or something, I was just following your code, could you make my answer correct if it helped, thanks! I’ll update it when displaying the college as well

Comment: I have changed my answer to include the college and city, please take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your code,

```
import random #goes on top

random.choice(list(schoollist_dict.values()))
```

So something like this,

```
if user_input == "random college":
    rando_college, rando_city = random.choice(list(schoollist_dict.items()))
    print(rando_college, rando_city)
```

Make sure you `import random` on top.

I created a textfile with 2 columns and the code above works for me when I updated your code with it.

Your final code should look like this,

```
import random

def main():

    print("Welcome to University Locator!")
    user_input = input("Please enter the the name of the university or type 'random college'(press x to exit). ")

    city = ""
    while user_input.lower() != "x":
        with open("universitylist.txt") as file:
            schoollist_dict = {}
            for lineitem in file:
                lineitem = lineitem.replace("\n", "")
                school_city_list = lineitem.split(",")
                schoollist_dict.update({school_city_list[0]: school_city_list[1]})

            user_college = user_input.title()

            if user_input == "random college":
                rando_college, rando_city = random.choice(list(schoollist_dict.items()))
                print(rando_college, rando_city)

            elif user_college in schoollist_dict:
                print()
                print(f"College: {user_college}")
                print(f"City: {schoollist_dict[user_college]}")
                print()
            else:
                print(f"The college {user_college} does not exist in our database.")
                print()

        user_input = input("Please enter the the name of the university or type 'random college'(press x to exit). ")
    print("Session Terminated")

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()  # Main entry point for the applications
```